# Docker bare " in non-quoted-field

Tags: docker

I have a Docker script that I have been using for some time to compile js and css. I got a new laptop, and now the exact same script is throwing this error:

```
Running npm run build
invalid argument 
"type=bind,source=\"$path\\src/MyProject/wwwroot/dist\",dst=/work/wwwroot/dist" for "--mount" flag: parse error on line 1, column 18: bare " in non-quoted-field
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The actual script to run docker:

```
param (
    [string]$target = "build"
)    

Write-Host "Running npm run $target"
$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName

docker run -it --memory="500m" --memory-swap="1g" --rm `
                --mount type=bind,src="$path\src/MyProject/wwwroot/dist",dst=/work/wwwroot/dist `
                --mount type=bind,src="$path\src/MyProject/fed/dist",dst=/work/fed/dist `
                --mount type=bind,src="$path\src/MyProject/fed/.storybook",dst=/work/fed/.storybook `
                --mount type=bind,src="$path\src/MyProject/fed/src",dst=/work/fed/src `
                mytag npm run $target
```

So, if this worked on my old laptop, why am I suddenly getting this error? Some kind of plugin for Powershell (Thats how I trigger this)?

This is triggered by Powershell .Net Core 7. With Docker Desktop on top of WSL

### UPDATE

Pretty sure this is related to Powershell .Net Core. The script works fine in Windows Powershell.

Is this a setting of some sort?

Comment: Are the backticks in that part of your code or some artifact of posting to SO?

Comment: They are part of the code.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#passing-arguments-that-contain-quote-characters

Comment: OK. At least Im not crazy. Not obvious how to use that in this case, but at least I have somewhere to look

Comment: OK, not able to discern how to use this in the context of a docker file. Where ever I put it, I get the error: Missing expression after unary operator '--'.

Comment: @JeffreyMixon Can you add that as an actual answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to [a breaking change in PowerShell 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#passing-arguments-that-contain-quote-characters):

> Some native commands expect arguments that contain quote characters. PowerShell 7.3 changed the way the command line is parsed for native commands.

The quickest work-around to restore the original behavior:

```
$PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'legacy'
```

In general, rewriting native commands with the `Start-Process` cmdlet seems to be the best approach going forward.